# Indent first paragraph inside memoir's adjustwidth

Tags: indentation, memoir

In machine-generated LaTeX that produces endnotes in `memoir`, I put (generate) each paragraph inside an `adjustwidth` environment to get the paragraph indented `26pts` to line up with something else. Works fine, but I also want the first line of each of these paragraphs indented (additionally) by whatever the normal paragraph indent is. None of the crazy ideas I've tried, like:

```
\begin{adjustwidth}{26pt}{0pt}\par\setlength{\parindent}{1cm}\indent ...
```

produces success. Seems like the `adjustwidth` environment really doesn't want to indent that first paragraph (or my general LaTeX knowledge is too weak). Any ideas where I'm going wrong or what else I might try?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to obtain your paragraph indent is to merely use `\hspace{\parindent}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}% http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{adjustwidth}{26pt}{0pt}
\hspace{\parindent}\lipsum[2-3]
\end{adjustwidth}

\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Works perfectly -- thank you so much!